# Why does python ask me to input the same thing over and over again after it has been already entered - (smtpib - gmail)

Tags: python, email, python-3.x, input, smtplib

I have this script that allows the user to send emails. However, when the user says yes to "Do you want to send another email" and then yes to "Do you want to switch accounts", why does the login then not work? After I enter a different username and password, it just asks for it again and again, even though the credentials are correct. Here is my code:

```
end = ("false")
end2 = ("false")
while True:
    if (end == "true"):
        break
    print ("Contacting server...")
    user = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    user.starttls()
    while True:
        euser = input("Enter Gmail Username: ")
        epass = input("Enter Gmail Password: ")
        try:
            user.login(euser, epass)
        except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
            print ("Invalid Credentials!")
            continue
        break
        while True:
            if (end == "true" or end2 == "true"):
                break
            user.login(euser, epass)
            print ("Retrieving Files")
            subjectinput = input("Enter Subject: ")
            msginput = input("Enter Message: ")
            msg = ("\n"+msginput)
            sourcemail = (euser)
            while True:
                targetmail = input("Enter Your Recipient: ")
                try:
                    user.sendmail(sourcemail, targetmail, 'Subject: {}\r\n\r\n{}'.format(subjectinput, msg))
                except (smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused):
                    print ("Invalid Recipient!")
                    continue
                break
            user.sendmail(sourcemail, targetmail, 'Subject: {}\r\n\r\n{}'.format(subjectinput, msg))
            print ("Email Sent")
            ask = input("Whould you like to send another one [Y/N]: ")
                if(ask == "n" or ask == "N" or ask == "no" or ask == "No"):
                    end = ("true")
                    break
                if(ask == "y" or ask == "Y" or ask == "yes" or ask == "Yes"):
                    newuser = input("Do you want to switch accounts [Y/N]: ")
                    if (newuser == "n" or newuser == "N" or newuser == "no" or newuser == "No"):
                        continue
                    if (newuser == "y" or newuser == "Y" or newuser == "yes" or newuser == "Yes"):
                        end2 = "true"
                        break
```

Any answers are greatly appreciated. Thanks, I am fairly new at python :)

Comment: Unrelated, but don't do `end = "False"` and then check `if end == "True":` - just do `end = False` and check `if end:`. Also, you don't need parentheses unless calling a function or constructing a tuple.

Comment: ok sure, gonna change that

Comment: @TimPietzcker, your answer does not fix my problem, can you edit it? Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Another thing: In Python, you can write `if ask.lower() in ("y", "yes"):` instead of `if (ask == "y" or ask == "Y" or ask == "yes" or ask == "Yes"):`

Comment: Or even if ask.lower().startswith('y')

Comment: Got it, I will change this after this :) thanks

Comment: You seem to be new to programming in general. Please learn what functions are and _use them_, frequently... If you had structured your code into smaller parts, you probably wouldn't have had this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this part:

```
while True:
    euser = input("Enter Gmail Username: ")
    epass = input("Enter Gmail Password: ")
    try:
        user.login(euser, epass)
    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        print ("Invalid Credentials!")
        continue
    break
```

When login succeeds, the next statement that is executed is `break`, and that throws you back to the beginning of the outer `while` loop. You need to move the `break` into the `try` statement (and you can remove the `continue` because you're now at the end of the loop anyway), and outdent the following `while` loop so it's on the same level as the previous one:

```
while True:
    euser = input("Enter Gmail Username: ")
    epass = input("Enter Gmail Password: ")
    try:
        user.login(euser, epass)
        break
    except smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError:
        print ("Invalid Credentials!")

while True:
    if end == "true" or end2 == "true": # better use booleans and `if end or end2:`
        break
    # unnecessary: user.login(euser, epass)
    print ("Retrieving Files")
```

Comment: after I removed the break, then it just throws me back to this while True and asks for me to enter it again. And I can't even login to get to the second part now.

Comment: Hmm, why are you calling `user.login()` a second time? You should already be logged in after the above code.

Comment: because it was just a try statement

Comment: any statement is the body of a try is guaranteed to be executed, and if an exception is raised, it is not "reversed" or "undone".

Comment: @TimePietzcker I did that and when I chose to use another user, it did the repeat input/prompt thing again. Not fixed :/

Comment: Well, you will need to reset `end2` to `False` when you do that, of course - your logic is rather confusing, and that's not helped by the unintuitive variable names.